# Установка библиотеки в проект Laravel

Tags: laravel

Возникла необходимость добавить скачанную на локальный диск Laravel-библиотеку в директорию с Laravel-проектом. Т.е. с установкой всех файлов и зависимостей. Погуглив по данной теме, в моём больном воображении сформировалось некое представление о том, что решение подобной задачи, сводится к указанию директории к устанавливаемой библиотеке (в данном случае это директория `~/library/mydownloadlibrary`) в файле `composer.json` в корне самого Laravel-проекта. Т.е. что-то вроде

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "~/library/mydownloadlibrary"
  }
]
```

Потом, из директории с проектом 
cd `/var/www/meta.tt/laravelproject`

Подтягиваем зависимости из указанной директории `~/library/mydownloadlibrary`

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Ну и конечно же ничего не меняется : `\`

В освоении Laravel делаю первые шаги. 
Был ли у кого опыт решения подобных задач и каким материалом Вы при этом руководствовались? Также замечательно было бы ознакомиться с последовательностью действий, которые необходимо выполнить для такого переноса.

[image: структура скачанной библиотеки]
[image: структура Laravel-проекта]

Comment: А почему бы просто не дать композеру всё установить самому? `composer require packageName`

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь стандартным способом подключения пакетов для composer:
`composer require *название_пакета*`.

Если же править вручную файл composer.json то есть [отличный сайт](https://packagist.org) для формирования зависимостей: 
-ищешь нужный пакет и копируешь все необходимые зависимости к себе в файл. 
-выполняешь команду
 `composer install`

После чего, пакет должен заработать

Comment: Спасибо за линк! Полезный ресурс!

Сейчас начинают наблюдаются некоторые подвижки. В    параметре "require" с composer.json, который размещён в директории проекта, добавил значение "destributor/library", из параметра "name" указанного в файле composer.json устанавливаемой библиотеки.

    "require"{
        "destributor/library":"*"
    },